# FaceIDRecoginition feature not implemented but asking to add NSFaceIDUsageDescription key in info.plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, face-id

No feature is added related to FaceID detection. I have not added

> LocalAuthentication.framework

in my application. I am using passcode for user authentication for my application. One of my client using faceID to unlock the screen, reported an issue that after unlocking the screen using faceID app is getting crashed.

I checked the issue in simulator as iPhone X is not available with me. I followed the following step to reproduce issue.

Hardware -> FaceID -> Enrolled.

I got following log in console.

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain
>   an NSFaceIDUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

As I mentioned earlier, I have not implemented any code to detect faceID then why I am facing above issue?

Comment: code is similar to Touch ID you don't need to code separately  just add NSFaceIDUsageDescription to info.plist then it will work in iPhone X without crash

Comment: How are you using a passcode to unlock the screen?  What code?

Comment: @Paulw11 In the logic to generate passcode LocalAuthentication.framework has been used.

Comment: So you are using the local authentication framework. If the user has biometrics set up then local authentication will use it; iOS won't force the user to enter a passcode if they have FaceID or TouchID. You need to provide the FaceID description.

Answer (score 1):

Your application will only crash on an actual device, if **FaceIdUsageDescription** is missing.

I would recommend you to add the **FaceIdUsageDescription** to the plist, as **LocalAuthentication.framework** will automatically authenticate with FaceID if device supports it and you application supports Biometrics(even TouchID).

[image: FaceID privacy policy]

I have seen these issue with already published banking application on AppStore. Adding the privacy policy to the plist will do the trick.

> Important: To protect user privacy, an iOS app that links on or after iOS 11 and that would access Face ID if the hardware supports it, must statically declare the intent to do so. Include the NSFaceIDUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file and provide a purpose string for this key. If your app attempts to access Face ID without a corresponding purpose string, your app may exit.
>   This key is supported in iOS 11 and later.

[Documentation Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW75)